# How to point to file in content in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, audio

I am trying to point to a file in the content of my XNA project. By default the method looks in the bin folder

```
enigine.play("Sound.wav")
```

How do I direct it to the content?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "direct it to the content"?

Comment: Content is a term used in XNA, its the directory in the project that holds most resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ContentManager.Load<SoundEffect>()` method:

```
var sound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sound");
sound.Play();
```

where `Content` is a reference to your `ContentManager` instance.

Comment: Is there a way to get it in the form of a string?