# What is the file path for references added in Content project in XNA?

Tags: c#, .net, file, xna

This problem is somewhat similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103839/how-to-point-to-file-in-content-in-xna)

In my case, I have a text file. And since there is no content importer that works for text file, I have to write my own functions using stream readers. What I am trying to accomplish is to read from the text file, and set a few values accordingly into the options screen. I have added all necessary references, but using "../options.txt" as filepath does not work. Quite possibly the filepath is resolved to something else than Content folder. How do I then proceed with it?

Also, I am getting errors saying "attempt to access method (System.IO....ctor) failed". Is it that I am missing to add some other reference?

Comment: If it's a text file that's going to bundled with the game and isn't meant to be modified by players I'd recommend just creating a custom content importer for it.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I needed a custom importer as it is supposed to be read/write access. Although, I have just used the code given by Andy, for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this have to work on the xBox 360? If so it's not possible to just use the filesystem like you can in Windows, you'll need to use a storage device. To be honest I would just use this method anyway so if you decide to take your game on to WP7 or 360 it'll just work.

There is a nice demo game that loads and saves data on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203921.aspx) Microsoft page as well as a description of what it's doing

This is taken from the demo, it shows how to open a storage container and serialize some config data to it, the load operation is just as simple.

```
// Create the data to save.
SaveGameData data = new SaveGameData();
data.PlayerName = "Hiro";
data.AvatarPosition = new Vector2(360, 360);
data.Level = 11;
data.Score = 4200;

// Open a storage container.
IAsyncResult result =
    device.BeginOpenContainer("StorageDemo", null, null);

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

StorageContainer container = device.EndOpenContainer(result);

// Close the wait handle.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.Close();

string filename = "savegame.sav";

// Check to see whether the save exists.
if (container.FileExists(filename))
    // Delete it so that we can create one fresh.
    container.DeleteFile(filename);

// Create the file.
Stream stream = container.CreateFile(filename);

// Convert the object to XML data and put it in the stream.
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveGameData));
serializer.Serialize(stream, data);

// Close the file.
stream.Close();

// Dispose the container, to commit changes.
container.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. A bit of a difficult solution than normal methods, but it gave me full access to those files.